# Cannot Launch EMR Jobflow using Temporary Credentials from EC2 IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have an instance which has been assigned an EC2 IAM role. I cannot create an EMR jobflow from this instance using the temporary credentials that having a Role assigned instance provides, I get the following response from the API:

```
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>ValidationError</Code>
    <Message>Service role and InstanceProfile are required for calls made with temporary credentials provided by STS</Message>
  </Error>
```

Googling this error message has revealed absolutely nothing. I get the same response from the API whether I use the AWS CLI or `boto` directly. In an attempt to follow the advice of this error message, I have tried passing `{InstanceProfile: <instance_profile_name>}` to the `api_params` argument for the `run_jobflow` method in boto, but still get the same error. I also tried using the `service_role` argument for `run_jobflow`, that also failed. Passing both together also failed.

According to this [page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/UsingTokens.html) from Amazon docs, EMR should support STS and EC2 IAM roles, so wondering if anyone has gotten this to work before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working in java. Like Sam, I specified a service role and jobflow role. It was a surprise to me that an error about InstanceProfile required that I set jobflow role. ex:

```
myRunJobFlowRequest.setServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole");
myRunJobFlowRequest.setJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
```

The other thing I did was in my cloud formation template, I granted the AmazonElasticMapReduceFullAccess policy to my instance role. ex:

```
"Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonElasticMapReduceFullAccess",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": "*",
                  "Resource": "*"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

Comment: I was using boto and to get this to work i needed to set:

job_flow_role='EMR_EC2_DefaultRole'
service_role='EMR_DefaultRole'

In my call to run_jobflow

Comment: This policy allows the affected resources to perform any AWS action that they like. That might be excessive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I managed to get this working, using:

- An explicit `service-role` (using the `EMR_DefaultRole` as a template)
- An explicit `jobflow-role` (using the `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole` as a template)
- Granting `iam:PassRole` permissions (for the `service-role` resource) to the EC2 IAM role